# How do I provide update data to my Playstation 3?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I bought a new PS3 Slim and when I powered it up it said "System cannot run correctly" and that I need to connect to a storage media that contains update data of version 4.81 or later.

I don't know what that means, can someone clarify this? What do I need to do?

Comment: It means you have to download the update from the Sony PlayStation site on to a USB following the instructions on the site

Answer (score 2):

Download the PS3 system software from https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/ps3-system-software/

Make a folder called "PS3" on a FAT32 formatted USB drive.

Create a folder called "UPDATE" in the "PS3" folder.

Put the file "PS3UPDAT.PUP" in the  "UPDATE" folder on the USB.

Plug the USB drive in to the PS3.

Hold the power button on the PS3 until the unit beeps three times, then let go.

Hold the power button again until you hear 2 slow beeps then 2 quick beeps, then let go again.

You should now get instructions on the screen and be able to update the PS3 from the menu.